# How to "override" the Index() of the AccountController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

As you probably already know, the AccountController is no longer available since 2.0.
Thanks to the New Scaffolded Item, everything can be managed via Identity.Pages.

But my question is, how do I retrieve a parameter from the url?

In 2.0 we would have done so :

```cs
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string parameter)
    { 
        [...]
    }
}
```

But in 3.1 how do we do it, since the AccountController doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto hello, well, I've already read this article, but it doesn't actually talk about my problem.

Comment: The docs do explain this though. If you want the default Identity UI, then it is bundled. If you want to replace things (e.g. with additional logic), then you can scaffold the Identity UI into your application at which point you can modify it then. – Or is your question specifically how you can modify the Razor pages that the Identity scaffolding creates?

Comment: @poke To make this clear, what I want is to be able to set as parameter an element of an url (as specified in 2.0 just above) in the actions Index, Register or Login, ect.

Comment: @Hashka Do you mean you are using AccountController and Scaffold Identity together? And you want to navigate to the action methods in AccountController, and transfer parameters?

Comment: Hi @Hashka, Whether the reply has solved the problem or is there any update about this thread? If you have any question about my reply, please let me know freely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using AccountController and the Scaffold Identity together, and want to navigate to the action method in the AccountController and transfer parameters.

If that is the case, you could refer the following sample code:

1. Add the parameter at the end of the url:

   Code in the View page:

   ```
     <a href="~/Account/Login?name='aaa'" >Login</a>
   ```

   Code in the Login action method:

   ```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet] 
        public IActionResult Login(string name)
        {
            ViewData["name"] = name;
            return View();
        }
    }
   ```
2. using routing attributes

   Code in the View Page:

   ```
   <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-name="dillion">Account</a>
   ```

   or

   ```
    <a href="~/Account/Login/aaa >Login</a>
   ```

   Code in the Login Action method:

   ```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Account/Login/{name}")]
        public IActionResult Login(string name)
        {
            ViewData["name"] = name;
            return View();
        }
    }
   ```

The screenshot as below:
[image]

For the Scaffold Identity pages, if you check the url, you can see they are in the Identity areas, the link as below:

```
  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

Reference:

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Hello, I take the liberty of answering you after several attempts. In fact, from my many attempts, even though the AccountController is no longer accessible in 3.1, I guess it doesn't have an Index() method.
So I have "Add New Scaffolded Item" -> Override all files.
And I modified them one by one. It's REALLY a shame, it's a lot of wasted time for nothing.